# Nested statements, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: python

If I entered '5' for limits and '3' for copies, I want the output to be

```
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5
```

and this is my code

```
limit = int(input("Limit: ")
copies = int(input("Copies: ")
count = 1

for i in range(copies):
     for j in range(limit):
          print(count, end= " ")
          count += 1
     if count == limit: count = 0
print()
```

But the output from this code is

```
1 2 3 4 5
6 7 8 9 10
11 12 13 14 15
```

Why is it that my "if count == limit: count = 0" seems to not do anything?

Comment: Why do you need to check the value of `count` there? Just resetting it to 1 outside of the inner loop (i.e. same place as your if statement) will do what you want?

Comment: How about printting `i + 1` ?

Comment: My thought process in that code is,  when count = limit, I want count to be reset to 0 so that it counts from 1 to 5, 3 times.

Comment: @LiamEmery but if the inner for loop has finished, then that line has finished printing. You don't need to check anything, just reset it to the starting value.

Comment: @Ben Thank you for that

Answer (score 6):

Let’s look at the iterations manually: You start with `count = 1`.

So in the first iteration for `copies`, the inner loop runs for `limit=5` times. After each inner iteration, `count` is incremented by one. So after 5 iterations, the `count` will be incremented by one *five times*. So the value after the inner loop will be `6`.

At this point, you check whether `count` is equal to the value of `limit`. So you check whether `6` is equal to `5` which is obviously not true. Thus, the variable does not reset and the next outer iteration runs.

Since you never decrease the value of `count`, the check will never be able to become true, so `count` will continuously increase without ever being reset.

To fix this, simply remove the check and just reset `count` regardless of its value. Since you always run the inner loop `limit` times, you will always know how often you would have incremented `count`, so there is no reason to check that:

```
for i in range(copies):
     for i in range(limit):
          print(count, end= " ")
          count += 1
     count = 1
```

You also want to reset the value to `1` to match the initial case and in order to have the first value in the row be `1`.

Answer (score 0):

Because when you do `range(limit)`, it only goes to `limit-1`.

e.g. `range(3`) will give `[0, 1, 2]`, so the last count will always be `limit + 1`.

You can have an alternative solution where you reset `count = 1`, in outer loop or you can check if `count - 1 == limit`.

Comment: Note that the loop value is never being used, so the range of values that `range(limit)` makes you loop through does not really matter much.

Comment: Yeah, I know, just wanted to point out why if condition is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that if.
Simply put the reset statement after your inner `for`

Answer (score 0):

Simply initialize the `count` variable inside your outer `for` loop and you don't have to reset it afterwards:

```
limit = int(input("Limit: ")
copies = int(input("Copies: ")

for i in range(copies):
    count = 1
    for j in range(limit):
        print(count, end= " ")
        count += 1
print()
```

But you could do this more effectively:

```
limit = int(input("Limit: ")
copies = int(input("Copies: ")

sequence = range(1, limit+1)
for i in range(copies):
    print(" ".join(sequence))
```